# TFS work items for tracking tasks

Tags: tfs, report, project-management, tracking

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and TFS onlin. I have created a TFS project using "MSF for CMMI" process template because it allows devs to estimate tasks, specify the remaining, etc. 
Questions:

1) How can make the estimation of the work item read only? I don't want anybody to change that value once it has been set.

2) I need to create a report that shows what each dev has done each week, indicating task and hours. I tested MS Project integration with TFS and it's great but some columns like start date and end date only exists in MS Project so I need to ask each developer when they have started and finished each task manually.

3) What reports do you recommend for tracking devs and tasks?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your first question: you'll have to modify Task work item type definition in TFS:

- export existing definition using witadmin.exe tool (you can find it in your Visual Studio folder):

`witadmin.exe exportwitd /collection:<collection URL> /p:<project name> /n:Task /f:task.xml`

- Modify exported xml by adding CANNOTLOSEVALUE and FROZEN rules to the Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate field definition:

```
<FIELD name="Original Estimate" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate" type="Double" reportable="measure" formula="sum">
    <HELPTEXT>The original estimate of work required to complete the task (in person hours)</HELPTEXT>
    <CANNOTLOSEVALUE />
    <FROZEN />
</FIELD>
```

- Import the updated xml back to TFS:

`witadmin.exe importwitd /collection:<collection URL> /p:<project name> /f:task.xml`

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer but I'm talking about TFS online as specified in the question. Because of that, I don't have access to the commands you proposed. Thanks again.

Comment: My bad, I missed that you were asking about VSO. VSO doesn't allow customization right now, so unfortunately I don't think you'll be able to make estimation field read-only.